# how can I add to static int +1?

Tags: c++, class, static

If I want to update my static id to be `id+=1` every time I create new Robot, 
how can I do that and where? 
i try this but it still don't work

```
class Robot{
Robot(){
    static int id_count=0;
    id=id_count++;
}
int id;
int x;
int y;
}
```

Comment: Add a constructor with a local static variable. Make id non static.

Comment: When you want to do something every time you create an object, doing it in a constructor is the natural choice.

Comment: Three answers so far have recommended doing it in the `Robot` class' constructor. That's very **bad advice**, because it leads to brittle code: add another constructor, and forget to do this also there, and you're off the road. Instead do it in the constructor of a class dedicated to the purpose of counting, and use an instance of that class as a data member. Don't forget (as in those answers) to decrement in the destructor, unless you just want to know the total number of instantiations.

Comment: @user0042: Thanks for that link, that's very useful. :)

Comment: ***i try this but it still don't work*** You will have to show why this is not working.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, Decrementing could be dangerous if things are destroyed out of order (e.g., a free store object being destroyed and causing the next object to have the same ID as the previously created object).

Comment: Also your question is still confusing as the answers demonstrate. One answer is calculating id to be the total # of Robots that are in existence (all instances have this count as id) while the other answer gives each Robot an increasing id so each Robot would have a unique id.

Comment: @chris; Oh sorry. I now see it's meant to be an id, not a count. Mea culpa.

Comment: Sorry again for changing my comment while a response to it was posted. It's that day today. But anyway, the address of an object is good unique id, unless id's need to persist across separate consecutive instantiations.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it could be to place it in the constructor.

```
class Robot{
public:
    Robot() {
        static int id_count=0;
        id = id_count++;
    }
    int id;
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

Comment: Codes aren't working and giving error `Explicit Type is missing`

Comment: Yes. It was missing an int before id_count. Updated and fixed now.

Comment: There's another error. The constructor should always be declared `public`. Your constructor will never be called upon creation of new Robot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the constructor:

```
class Robot {
    static int id;
    Robot() { ++id; }
    int x; 
    int y;
};
```

If you want each robot to have its own id then:

```
class Robot {
   static int refcount;
   int id;
   int x;
   int y;
   public:
     Robot() {
        id = ++refcount;
     }
}
```

Comment: Your programs giving linker error : `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "private: static int Robot::refcount" (?refcount@Robot@@0HA)`

Answer (score 0):

Make a `static` variable (not `id`), initialize it, and increment in a constructor and assign to the `id`.

> Working and the most simplified codes.

```
class Robot
{
    static int count;
    int id, x, y;
public:
    Robot()
    {
        id = count++;
    }
};

int Robot::count = 0;
```

> Complete Working program:

```
#include<iostream>

class Robot
{
    static int count;
    int id, x, y;
public:
    void show(){std::cout << id << std::endl;}
    Robot(){id = count++;}
};

int Robot::count = 0;

int main()
{
    Robot a, b, c;
    a.show();
    b.show();
    c.show();
    return 0;
}
```

You can run [here](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/HNMKKEKXET)

Answer (score 0):

You need a static int id inside the class so when another instance of `Robot` is created, it can access it too.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Robot {
public:
  static int id;
  int x, y;

  // Give the class a constructor. This is called whenever a new instance of
  // Robot is created.
  Robot(int x, int y) {
    this -> x = x;
    this -> y = y;
    ++id;

    cout << "I am a new robot." << endl;
    cout << "My x value is " << x << endl;
    cout << "My y value is " << y << endl;
    cout << "My id is " << id << endl;
  }
};

int Robot::id = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  // Create 5 new instances of robots and
  // say how many robots have been created.
  for(int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
    Robot r = Robot(1 * i, 1 * (i * 2));
    cout << "There are now " << r.id << " robots" << endl;
    cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
I am a new robot.
My x value is 0
My y value is 0
My id is 1
There are now 1 robots

I am a new robot.
My x value is 1
My y value is 2
My id is 2
There are now 2 robots

I am a new robot.
My x value is 2
My y value is 4
My id is 3
There are now 3 robots

I am a new robot.
My x value is 3
My y value is 6
My id is 4
There are now 4 robots

I am a new robot.
My x value is 4
My y value is 8
My id is 5
There are now 5 robots
```

Comment: but what if I want to put more args in my class? my constractor need to get int x, int y also , and to update the id to be id+1

Comment: @ShacharOren I have edited the constructor to take an `x` and `y` value.

Comment: There's no need to use a global. A static data member suffices (or one of the other suggestions made here). As a global, `static` means it has internal linkage, not anything about storage duration. All this ends up doing is giving the entire file access to the variable instead of limiting access to the class that needs it.

Comment: Thanks @chris I've moved the static variable to inside the class. Thanks for the tip.